# Will a SQL Server Replication Reinitialization overwrite data?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a customer's server which is giving me a "Snapshot not available" error when trying to do it's replication.

From what I've read, I need to mark it for reinitialization.

Now, here's the important part:
On the subscribing server, there is information that's being added to the database via a manual interface, that the information on the publishing server (which serves to bring in XML feeds and then publish the inserts to the web server's database) can't overwrite.

So, what I need to know is whether executing the reinitialization will overwrite the subscribing server with the publishing server's copy of the data *which does not contain these manual entries*? (I'm not the person who set this up, otherwise I would have set it up with the subscriber's updates being propagating back to the publishing server)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you must end up reinitializing and you cannot lose data on the subscriber, then you are going to have to probably generate/script the unsynched changes using tablediff. This sounds like the case if the subscriber is looking for the replication snapshot. After the data is corrected you can blow away and recreate the subsciption.